# Does a compound index where the prefix field is unique make any sense?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, indexing, nosql

Let's take the field `_id`, which is unique across the collection.

Does it make any sense to have any compound index where `_id` is the prefix eg:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  A: 1
}
```

Would the index above be any more efficient than simply the index of:

```
{
  _id: 1
}
```

If so, can you give an example of a query where that is the case?

Comment: No, both will be equally efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to disagree with [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77270712/does-a-compound-index-where-the-prefix-field-is-unique-make-any-sense#comment136225186_77270712) and say that the answer is: Sure, there are very specific circumstances where it makes sense. The most notable one that comes to mind is if you want the index to [cover the query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) which we'll explore below.

In this answer, consider a collection `foo` with the following indices:

```
> db.foo.getIndices()
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  { v: 2, key: { u: 1 }, name: 'u_1', unique: true },
  { v: 2, key: { u: 1, A: 1 }, name: 'u_1_A_1' }
]
```

And the following query:

```
.find({u:123},{A:1, _id:0})
```

Using the single field `unique` index yields the following plan:

```
> db.foo.find({u:123},{A:1, _id:0}).hint({u:1}).explain().queryPlanner.winningPlan
{
  stage: 'PROJECTION_SIMPLE',
  transformBy: { A: 1, _id: 0 },
  inputStage: {
    stage: 'FETCH',
    inputStage: {
      stage: 'IXSCAN',
      keyPattern: { u: 1 },
      indexName: 'u_1',
      ...
      indexBounds: { u: [ '[123, 123]' ] }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the compound index, however, shows something different:

```
> db.foo.find({u:123},{A:1, _id:0}).hint({u:1, A:1}).explain().queryPlanner.winningPlan
{
  stage: 'PROJECTION_COVERED',
  transformBy: { A: 1, _id: 0 },
  inputStage: {
    stage: 'IXSCAN',
    keyPattern: { u: 1, A: 1 },
    indexName: 'u_1_A_1',
    ...
    indexBounds: { u: [ '[123, 123]' ], A: [ '[MinKey, MaxKey]' ] }
  }
}
```

The notable difference here is the absence of the `FETCH` stage when the compound index is used. By the way, the compound index is the one that is chosen naturally by the database in my testing (`6.0`).

In a related manner, if the query were to include a query predicate on the `A` field then the compound index could check that condition whereas the single field index could not. With an equality condition on the unique field, the downside of that `FETCH` from using the single field index is capped though (only a single document could be retrieved and discarded unnecessarily).

So, yes, there are cases where a compound index prefixed on a unique field could provide some value. That said, indexing is often about finding the right balance for the overall workload. So the micro-optimizations that the compound index could provide for a specific query or two might not be worth the tradeoff of forcing the database to maintain a whole new index.

*In this answer I've used a `u` field rather than `_id` as posed in the initial question. This is because, at the time of writing, MongoDB has some special handling of the `_id` field. So generalizing and working with a different field/index that is `unique` makes it easier to demonstrate and reason about.*

Comment: If a fetch stage is needed, is there a way to know exactly how many docs or MB that were fetched from storage vs RAM? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77273999/in-the-mongodb-explain-does-it-reveal-the-number-of-documents-fetched-from-disk

Comment: Also note that once the database gets large enough to require sharding, the only way to ensure a unique field across shards is to have the unique field as a prefix of the shard key index.